# async await promise rejection in react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks, axios

I think I am missunderstanding how the async await is working, especially with a function from another file. So I want to get an adress from longitude and latitude using an axios call on an API

```
import { getAddressFromLongLat } from "../hooks/queries-hook";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Component = (props) => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFromLongLat = async () => {
      if (props.coords) {
        const response = await getAddressFromLongLat(props.coords);
        console.log("response from nominatim " + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        setAddress(response);
      }
    };
    fetchFromLongLat();
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
```

then into `queries-hook.js`

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getAddressFromLongLat = async (coords) => {
  const URL = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse";
  const response = await axios.get(URL, {
    params: {
      format: "json",
      lat: coords.lat,
      lon: coords.long
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  });
  return {
    street: response.address.road + " " + response.address.house_number,
    cp: response.address.postcode,
    city: response.address.town,
    country: response.address.country_code.toUpperCase()
  };
};
```

can someone explain me how I should write correctly the code with those async await to not have the error:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is
> not an object (evaluating 'response.address.road')

Comment: What is the expected behavior when `address.road` does not exists on response object? Are you sure your response contains it everytime? Due to it is async function - reject is happening because the exception was thrown.. You should check what your `response` is in that case. Or wrap the `return` statement where exception is thrown with `try-catch` and handle it in the way you want

Comment: Also, your `useEffect` is missing a dependency `props.coords` in the `depsArray`. Due to that your hook will be executed only once and will not react on props changes. It might be ok for your case for now but can lead to some bugs later.

Comment: everything working fine, I have check the response, it's just that the return doesn't wait the response being ready before returning the response.address.road

Comment: Which `coords` do you send so I can reproduce your issue?

Comment: you can use any ^^, but here is some : {
                "lat": 50.806002951249546,
                "long": 4.410705976188183
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is due to `response` does not contains `address` property and all the rest. But `response.data` do.

You had to add a `console.log(response);` before `return` to figure that out. The output for `{ "lat": 50.806002951249546, "long": 4.410705976188183 }`  will be this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "place_id": 113461740,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "way",
    "osm_id": 30994925,
    "lat": "50.8066154",
    "lon": "4.410838323013642",
    "display_name": "Parc sportif des Trois Tilleuls, Avenue Léopold Wiener - Léopold Wienerlaan, Le Triangle - De Driehoek, Ватермаль-Буафор, Брюссельский столичный регион, 1170, Бельгия",
    "address": {
      "leisure": "Parc sportif des Trois Tilleuls",
      "road": "Avenue Léopold Wiener - Léopold Wienerlaan",
      "neighbourhood": "Le Triangle - De Driehoek",
      "town": "Ватермаль-Буафор",
      "county": "Брюссельский столичный регион",
      "region": "Брюссельский столичный регион",
      "ISO3166-2-lvl4": "BE-BRU",
      "postcode": "1170",
      "country": "Бельгия",
      "country_code": "be"
    },
    "boundingbox": [
      "50.8042107",
      "50.80902",
      "4.4079878",
      "4.4130556"
    ]
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "",
  ...
  (cutted)
}
```

So fixed function:

```
const getAddressFromLongLat = async (coords) => {
  // switched to HTTPS here also
  const URL = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse";
  const response = await axios.get(URL, {
    params: {
      format: "json",
      lat: coords.lat,
      lon: coords.long
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  });
  const { data } = response; // equal to const data = response.data
  return {
    street: data.address.road + " " + data.address.house_number,
    cp: data.address.postcode,
    city: data.address.town,
    country: data.address.country_code.toUpperCase()
  };
};
```

Comment: ho yeah actually axios encaplsulate it in data... forgot that detail. Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Try = () => {

    const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);

    const getAddressFromLongLat = async () => {
        const URL = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse";
        const response = await axios.get(URL, {
            params: {
                format: "json",
                lat: 36.884804,
                lon: 30.704044
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        });
        const { data } = response; **// There is your mistake.**
        return {

            street: data.address.road + " " + data.address.house_number,
            cp: data.address.postcode,
            city: data.address.town,
            country: data.address.country_code.toUpperCase()
        };
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFromLongLat = async () => {
            if (1 === 1) {
                const response = await getAddressFromLongLat();
                console.log("response from nominatim " + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
                setAddress(response);
            }
        };
        fetchFromLongLat();
    }, []);

    console.log(address)
    return (
        <div>try</div>
    )
}

export default Try
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but may be you don't need use async...await in second function. This is like tako inside tako. But you need just two tako in one tako bell.